# Custom cross fade segue to and from black

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, segue, tvos

I'm developing an app for tvOS in Swift using `UIKit` and I would like to implement a black cross-fade segue between two ViewControllers that stands for the whole functionality and does not require any custom views or code added to the source and destination ViewControllers.

What I'm looking for is something like this:

[image]

I did search a lot and tried many things but had little luck in getting it to work. Two complications make it all the more difficult:

1. One of my `ViewControllers` are contained inside a `UISearchController`.
2. My backgrounds are not black.

I would appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a decent way of doing it. Here's a custom segue class that seamlessly performs the transition.

### StoryboardFadeToBlackSegue.swift

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class StoryboardFadeToBlackSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

  override func perform() {
    guard let window = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window else {
      super.perform()
      return
    }
    let overlay = UIView(frame: window.frame)
    overlay.layer.zPosition = 1
    overlay.backgroundColor = .black
    overlay.alpha = 0.0
    window.addSubview(overlay)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
      overlay.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: { _ in
      self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: {
          overlay.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: { _ in
          overlay.removeFromSuperview()
        })
      })
    })
  }
}
```

In order to use it, set this class as the associated Class in the attributes inspector for your Segue.

[image: setting the custom segue class]